# neither clearTimeout nor ClearInterval is not working

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have problem with setTimeout and clearTimeout.

my flash video player calls "onVideoFinish" function on finish event and calls "cancelVideoFinish" function on replay event.

what I am doing here is creating a playlist.
Belove code has setInterval, but I've tried both setTimeout(clearTimeout) and setInterval(clearInterval) and neither of them worked. I also tried defining callback function instead of calling "redirectPage" function.

on console I have somthing like:
---321---
+++null+++

```
var togoTimer = null;
function onVideoFinish() {
    if ($("#sidePlaylist").length > 0) {
        ...Some Stuff Here...
        if (togo) {
            togoTimer = setInterval("redirectPage('" + togo + "')", 3000);
        }
    }
}

function redirectPage(t) {
    console.log("+++" + togoTimer + "+++");
    window.location = t;
}

function cancelVideoFinish() {
    console.log("---" + togoTimer + "---");
    clearInterval(togoTimer);
    togoTimer = null;
}
```

Comment: Do not pass a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: And don't use `setInterval` to call `window.location=something` : as you leave the page it can be executed only once...

Comment: After you reload the page, the timer and everything else from the previous page will be gone.

Comment: @SLaks I also tried  togoTimer = setTimeout(function(){ console.log("+++" + togoTimer + "+++"); window.location = t; }, 3000);     at first I was using setTimeout (like in this comment and with clearTimout ofcourse). when it was not working I gave a try to setInterval.